# Impedir um segundo click no mesmo botão

Tags: java, javafx

Nesse jogo da memória, quando clico no primeiro botão e depois no segundo botão, tudo acontece conforme o algorítimo, mas quando dou dois cliques no primeiro botão, acontece um problema... queria saber como evitar um segundo click no primeiro botão clicado, tipo desativar ele para não poder receber um segundo click... porque o botão conta cada click que recebe, por isso que não pode haver mais que um click.

```
            for (int i=0; i<16; ++i){

            if (event.getSource() == buttons[i]){
                buttons[i].setGraphic(new ImageView(imgs[Aleatorio[i]]));//novo código
                //buttons[i].setVisible(true);
                NumeroClick++;
                if (NumeroClick == 1) PrimeiroClick = i;
                if (NumeroClick == 2){
                    SegundoClick = i;

                    ///////////////Clicks_não_conseguidos///////////////
                    if (Aleatorio[PrimeiroClick] != Aleatorio[SegundoClick]){     

                        pontos-=2;

                    Servico service = new Servico();

                    service.setOnSucceeded((WorkerStateEvent ev) -> {

                        buttons[PrimeiroClick].setGraphic(null); //novo código
                        buttons[PrimeiroClick].setDisable(false);                            
                        buttons[SegundoClick].setGraphic(null); //novo código
                        buttons[SegundoClick].setDisable(false); 

                    });               

                        service.start();

                    }  else {
                        ContAcertos++;
                        pontos+=10;
                    }
                    NumeroClick = 0;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Acho que te está a faltar um `if` se percebi bem o teu codigo... Depois de saberes que é o segundo click , aqui penso eu `if (NumeroClick == 2){` tens de verificar se não é no mesmo botão que o primeiro, se por acaso for igual tens de mandar repetir o click... Contudo não percebi como o teu código é executado, visto que percorres sempre dentro do `FOR` ... Na minha lógica devia de esperar um click e depois sim verificar se foi o primeiro ou o segundo se for o segundo e com o primeiro guardado numa variável fazes a comparação se está certo ou não...

Comment: Está usando jQuery ?

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução viável seria criando um *Listener*(Ouvinte) para quando seu butão for *clicado* ou sofrer qualquer alteração, ele alterar o estado dele até quando vc queira.

Outra seria vc adicionar um *Handler* para o botão.

---

Exemplo 1:

```
Button x = new Button();
    x.onActionProperty().addListener(listenerEvent -> {
        x.setDisable(true);
    });

//...
// Até certo momento

x.setDisable(false);
```

Exemplo 2:

```
Button x = new Button();
x.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, event -> {
    x.setDisable(true);
});

//...
// Até certo momento

x.setDisable(false);
```

---

Dê uma olhadinha nessa [página](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744334/button-onactionproperty-addlistener-is-not-working-in-javafx) em inglês que fala exatamente disso!

Comment: Fiz algo parecido, Yuri, mas o botão fica com uma aparência meio  transparente, diferente do original.

Comment: No caso, é esperado que ele fique assim, é o **estado desativado**, evitando _cliques_, no momento que vc fizer `x.setDisable(false)` ele volta ao **estado normal**. Assim ele evita de funcionar sem necessidade, no caso aqui, de dois cliques. [setDisabled](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setDisabled(boolean))

Comment: Você pode criar a lógica dentro do _Listener_ ou _Handler_ iniciando com _Disable_ *true* e terminando com _Disable_ *false*. Uma sugestão, no caso.

Comment: Em meu algoritmo, fica complicado usar Disable; porque no momento em que voto a habilitar, o problema voltará, caso o botão seja clicado novamente.